# DLL load failed while importing _arpack from scipy.integrate

Tags: python, scipy, anaconda

I am trying to import solve_ivp from scipy.intgrate

```
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp as odesolver
```

and i got this error:

```
line 9, in <module>
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp as odesolver

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\integrate\__init__.py", line 94, in <module>
    from ._bvp import solve_bvp

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\integrate\_bvp.py", line 8, in <module>
    from scipy.sparse.linalg import splu

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\__init__.py", line 114, in <module>
    from .eigen import *

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\eigen\__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    from .arpack import *

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\eigen\arpack\__init__.py", line 20, in <module>
    from .arpack import *

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\eigen\arpack\arpack.py", line 42, in <module>
    from . import _arpack

ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _arpack: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

i am trying to reinstall anaconda but it didn't work
i have tried to reinstall scipy using pip install but still got the error

any idea how to solve this error?
thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

This might be a wild guess but it seems anaconda has some issue with scipy.
May I suggest you the good ol' trick of reinstalling the dependencies ?

```
conda remove --force numpy scipy
pip install numpy scipy
```

They had an issue open for a while on [anaconda's github](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/6396), if you fancy the read.

Comment: I already did the following pip install but it did not work for me